# VueJS InertiaJS Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm implementing on Vue JS with Inertia a list where you can filter by name

```
data() {
        return {
            selectedUser: this.value,
            selected: null,
            search: '',
        }
    },

computed: {
        userlist: function(){
            return this.users.filter(function(user){
                return user.name.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
            });
        }
    },
```

and the component

```
<input class="form-input" placeholder="Search.." v-model="search">
<a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900 flex items-center" v-for="user in userlist" :key="user.id" @click.prevent="select(user)">
```

However, when I open the modal, where the component is, I get an error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined
```

I've already hardcoded the search value, like this

```
computed: {
        userlist: function(){
            return this.users.filter(function(user){
                return user.name.toLowerCase().match('John')
            });
        }
    },
```

and the component renders just fine. I'm not getting where the error could be, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does it show the same if you replace v-model with `selected` or any other values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem PROBABLY is that you're using the `this` keyword expecting it to be a **reference to your component instance**, but you're using it **inside a `function`** declaration, which creates a new context, causing `this` to be `undefined`.

```js
computed: {
    userlist: function(){
        // here, this is the component instance
        return this.users.filter(function(user){
            // --> function(user) { creates a new context
            // here, this is undefined and this.search will cause the error
            return user.name.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
        });
    }
}
```

To prevent this, you can use an arrow function, which will will keep the existing context. This means that the `this` keyword will still reference your component instance.

```js
computed: {
    userlist: function(){
        // here, this is the component instance
        return this.users.filter((user) => { // --> replaced function with an  arrow function
            // here, this is still a reference to the component instance
            return user.name.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed this what was causing the error. I'm sort of new to Vue Js and frontend in general, so this is helpful to me!

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way:

```
computed: {
    userlist: function(){
        const vm = this;
        return this.users.filter(function(user){
            return user.name.toLowerCase().match(vm.search.toLowerCase())
        });
    }
},
```